# ScrollView steps over parent element while no flex but can not be seen with flex

Tags: react-native

I'm currently doing an example of a Model View with a label and a ScrollView below it. However, in the ScrollView's style when I set with no flex it goes over the parent element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv1lH.png

While if I set flex: 1 to the ScrollView style, the content does not show on the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpiWi.png

Here is my code:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import ModalContent from './src/ModalContent';

export default class ModalTester extends Component {
  state = {
    isModalVisible: false
  };

  _toggleModal = () =>
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalStyle}>
            <ModalContent />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  modalStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  }
}
```

ModalContent.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import InfoBox from './InfoBox'

export default () => {
    return (
        <View styles={styles.containerStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>TRIP INFO</Text>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewStyle}>
                <InfoBox boxHeight={100} />
                <InfoBox boxHeight={200} />
                <InfoBox boxHeight={400} />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
    },

    headerStyle: {
        fontSize: 35,
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#be5bc2',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
    },

    scrollViewStyle: {
        marginTop: 10,
    }
}
```

InfoBox.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default ({boxHeight}) => {
    setContainerStyle = function(setHeight) {
        return ({
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 4,
            borderColor: "#000",
            height: setHeight,
            marginTop: 25,
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginRight: 20,
        });
    }

    return (
        <View style={this.setContainerStyle(boxHeight)}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and change `style` for `contentContainerStyle` in ScrollView and works for me.

It would look like this:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }} />
```